# Incorrect evaluation for Thue-Morse signed harmonic series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I would like to evaluate

$$s = 1 - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8} - ... + \frac{(-1)^{\textrm{binary digit sum}(n-1)}}{n} + ... $$

where the signs follow the [Thue-Morse sequence](http://oeis.org/A010060). When I try to evaluate

`Sum[ (-1)^Total[ IntegerDigits[ n - 1, 2]]/n, {n, 1, ∞}]`

using *Mathematica 7* I get

> ```
> Log[2]
> ```

This is incorrect. $$\log( 2) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \approx 0.693147$$ but $$s \approx 0.39876108810841881241$$ I checked this using *C#* and finite sums within *Mathematica*. This value is not in the inverse symbolic calculator, but since that is incomplete I still have some hope for an analytic summation.

The difference between these series can be expressed as a sum of positive terms $$\frac{2}{3\times 4} + \frac{2}{5\times 6} + \frac{2}{9\times 10} + \frac{2}{15\times 16}+\ldots+\frac{2}{n \times (n+1)}+ \ldots$$ where the sum is over all odd $n$ with even binary digit sum, so it is definitely the case that $s \lt \log( 2).$

I also tried

`Sum[ (-1)^Total[ IntegerDigits[ n - 1, 2]]/n, { n, 1, ∞, 2}]`

which equals $\frac{3}{2}s \approx 0.59814163216262821861$, but which instead evaluates to

> ```
> Sum::div: Sum does not converge
>
> Sum[ (-1)^(1 + n)/n, { n, 1, ∞, 2}]
> ```

So, is this a known bug?
What sorts of related sums are affected?
Is there a way to get the right answer from *Mathematica*?

Comment: Is the partial sum `Sum[(-1)^Total[IntegerDigits[n - 1, 2]]/n, {n, 1, m}]` also incorrect ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks: The partial sums seem to be correct. They agree numerically with computations in C#.

Comment: Do you agree on the output of `Total[IntegerDigits[n - 1, 2]]` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Yes, those values appear to be correct. Table[Total[IntegerDigits[n - 1, 2]], {n, 8}] produces the correct values {0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3}.

Comment: @Artes: I'm not sure what you would approve. I did not say the numerical calculations in C# were in any way an ultimate oracle. I checked the calculations in two quite different ways, with different algorithms and sources for error, and they agreed. As a result, I trust both.

Comment: @DouglasZare So this is not equal to Table[n+1, {n, 8}]; maybe this is the source of the problem.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Yes, in the infinite sums it appears that Total[IntegerDigits[n-1,2]] is replaced with something like n+1. In the finite sums it appears to be correctly evaluated.

Comment: The result obtained arises from the fact that `IntegerDigits[n - 1, 2]` returns unevaluated, and `Total` thereof then gives `n+1`. Not wrong, but also not what is wanted. To forestall this one might rewrite the summand as a "black box" function that only evaluates on explicit integer input, e.g. `f[n_Integer] := (-1)^Total[IntegerDigits[n - 1, 2]]/n`. Using this the sum returns unevaluated (no surprise there).

Comment: @DouglasZare I did not mean numerical calculations were not welcome. I guessed you would underline the problem in a bit clearer setting. Anyway I upvoted your question and I think it deserves more upvotes.

Comment: Just to throw another non-working idea onto the pile, `GeneratingFunction` won't work because the recurrence for the Thue Morse sequence (and thus also the summand here) is not simple enough for `GeneratingFunction` and `DifferenceRoot` to handle. Otherwise we could construct a whole power series / generating function and then evaluate at $x=1$.

Comment: Interestingly `Sum[(-1)^DigitCount[n - 1, 2, 1]/n, {n, 1, Infinity}]` does not evaluate to `Log(2)`.